# What is the RoadMap of SharePoint and for its Developer community?

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, sharepoint-server, visual-studio, 2016

My question is about what is the vision of Microsoft for SharePoint and what ways can we foresee will it affect us, the developers.

1. Will server side technologies remain in priority
2. What developments are taking place in App Model
3. [Where are we on new form builder replacing InfoPath, any migration of existing InfoPath is being discussed](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/130820/what-is-microsoft-replacing-infopath-with-in-next-iteration-of-sharepoint)?
4. What will be licensing structure (on premise and online)
5. VS updates for SharePoint client side object model, like intellisense for JSOM, online SDK etc.
6. What are the new api improvement.

Comment: A good reference to start you off is: http://roadmap.office.com/en-us

Comment: Closing this as only the product group could answer this definitively, anything else is speculation and not a fit for this type of forum.

Comment: @PirateEric thanks for your edit. I do have many open questions to SharePoint roadmap and have been seeking answer to them. I agree with your explanation as to why this forum shouldn't be used to seek this line of question. I think I will reword the question in time.

Comment: please do, we're here to help, but unfortunately most "why" questions don't fit here. the "How" and "What (am I doing wrong)" are the preferred questions