# What is Microsoft replacing InfoPath with, in next iteration of SharePoint

Tags: infopath, newform, update, 2016

I am aware of Microsoft's intention of discontinuing the InfoPath form in SharePoint.

I believe InfoPath with all its draw backs, still managed to cater to the needs of many IT professional in creating quick and easy Forms in SharePoint. In such a case what are they replacing it with.

**PS:** what is the case with InfoPath support in SharePoint Online/O365 in upcoming SharePoint versions.

Comment: Microsoft has not yet said anything more then that InfoPath 2013 is the last version but they will support it until 2022. Until then i think that most people will still continue to use infopath to create forms, or purchase a third-part product as Nintex or K2 solutions. But i'm sure Microsoft will come with something even greater then Infopath.

Comment: It feels to me like, going forward, Microsoft wants to limit how much we can customise SharePoint as power users and make us rely more on developers. The removal of the design view in SharePoint 2013 wasn't generally received well by power users. Want custom forms that are smart, with on the fly validation, etc? "Get a developer" Microsoft will tell you.

Of course, I could be completely wrong and Microsoft might introduce some fantastic new power-user tools for SharePoint 2016. We'll just have to wait and see...

Comment: My gut tells me we will learn a lot more at the upcoming Ignite conference.

Answer (score 1):

Just went through the following link [Update on InfoPath and SharePoint Forms](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/SharePoint-Conference/2014/SPC348)

I might be a bit late to the party but Microsoft SharePoint team is also taking recommendation from SharePoint Dev/User community [here](http://officeforms.uservoice.com/)

Answer (score 1):

For me there's no real replacement for InfoPath right now... 
Please find official post on the Microsoft site:
http://blogs.office.com/2014/01/31/update-on-infopath-and-sharepoint-forms/
As you can see in case of complex forms Microsoft still suggest to use InfoPath. Also please remember that InfoPath will be supported for next 8 years. And in terms of IT it's a lot of time...

Answer (score 0):

They are giving out mixed messages at Redmond. Some of their blogs don't give any real clue (as Per Tomasz' post above) yet they have given demos of something called Forms on Sharepoint Lists (FoSL). This appears to be the same form technology as used in the current Access 2013.

Have a look about halfway through this video for a very brief demo (full of marketing bull about modal screens): http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/SharePoint-Conference/2014/SPC348